# Destructuring objects with hyphenated keys

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

In my application I'm working with adding some pagination metadata to my store from my response header. One of the keys' names  is `Per Page` which translates to `per-page` in the object literal.

Is it at all possible to destructure hyphenated keys? I've tried making it into a computed property, camel-casing it, and making it into a plain string but to no avail. Any suggestions?

```
const { page, [per-page], total } = response.headers;

const { page, perPage, total } = response.headers;

const { page, "per-page", total } = response.headers;
```

Comment: You can't. The destructured key becomes a variable name in scope and must therefor be a valid JavaScript identifier. You just need to do it on a separate line: `const {page, total} = reponse; const perPage = response['per-page'];`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const { page, "per-page": perPage, total } = response.headers;
```

This will write the value with the key "per-page" into the `perPage` constant.

Comment: Thanks. Is there somewhere on MDN or in the docs that explain this workaround?

Comment: @CarlEdwards I don't think there's somewhere that has an example just like this, but the example ["Assigning to New Variable Names"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) covers the general behavior.

Comment: Great. Thanks again.